# extjs calendar doesn't show correct time after daylight saving time clock change

Tags: extjs, calendar

I have noticed that extjs calendar control doesn't show correct time after clock change due to daylight saving time. The times are shifted one hour ahead with respect to rows' headers.
Any idea what that could be?

[image]

Comment: Well, this is a hard problem to solve, what would you expect and why? Two events at 7 o'clock, one today and one yesterday - should they displayed side by side? Or with one hour difference or ... ?

Comment: No, you probably didn't understand me. I clicked at 06:00 and dragged up to 08:00. But, what is written (please see the green box) is 07:00-09:00. It should be 06:00-08:00.

Comment: Is it because of the timezone on the server being different than the timezone on the client?

Comment: Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: Looks like UTC vs local time issue. This fiddle might help -> offset: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#calendar-timezone

Nevertheless i dont like the implementation of this example. You might want to check timezones config here as well: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/components/calendar.html